# Tables in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I was told for years that table-less css is best practice. But I notice that bootstrap explicitly handles tables. So is using tables okay, but only within the bootstrap framework? Or is the whole concept of table-less css defunct?

Comment: For the layout you mean?

Comment: for example in row column display of financial reports and similar it is totaly safe to use a table.   but you should not use tables for layout of your page

Comment: Your question is too broad. Which scenario are you referring to? layout or tabular data? 
Is using tables ok? Yes, why wouldn't it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

People who told you that table-less css is best practice , probably refer to an older layout practice : once it was common to see entire pages composed by a giant table holding elements inside its cells.
This approach is now dead in favour of a div layout ( which bootstrap uses ).
This of course does not mean that you can not use tables inside your page, if it is convenient to do so.